# Why does my computer only boot into Windows XP?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-xp

I installed Ubuntu from a usb, but when I rebooted my computer after the installer finished, my computer booted into Windows XP. I didn't see any menu for selecting the operating system during boot.

How do I boot into Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you see the BIOS screen hold `Shift`. This will take you to the GRUB screen.
From there you can select which operating system you want to boot to.

If this doesn't work then you might have to repair GRUB by booting into a live CD.

Then open a terminal and type:

```
//To find out in which partition Ubuntu is installed
sudo fdisk -l
```

Mount the partition:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Now install GRUB in that partition:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda
```

Comment: Or boot from a live cd and install boot repair and let the magic happen for you.[link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). See 2nd option for details.